# Tracking extract with device type

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, tracking-extract

Is it possible to create a *Tracking Extract* activity in Automation studio that includes the type of device the recipient has Opened or Clicked on? Or should this be done via an *SQL Query* Activity? If so, please guide me to the page where the query is described.

**Update**: The Tracking Extract activity options

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating Tracking extract activity, select "Include User Agent Information" checkbox, it includes user agent data related to the open or click, such as operating system, email client, browser, or device.
Refer: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract_config.htm&type=5

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but I do not see this option in the Tracking Extract activity. Is this something that should be enabled via a support ticket?

Comment: Yes, you will have to raise a support ticket to get this enabled.

Comment: I just did. Thank you for your answer! So far, I have come across many features that are completely hidden from the user. For new users, this will be very confusing because the documentation pages do not mention that these features are by default not available. They do not even appear as "disabled", but are just non-existent. If one does not know they exist, they might go around for days trying to find alternatives. This is very unproductive!

Comment: I was told they are being sunsetted so are by default turned off. Looking at the data we got, the actual outcomes were not overly helpful from a strategic or operational perspective.